# Get all log Stream names by Group name pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have plenty of following log groups:

```
111111/myProj-1.0.190-Dev
111111/myProj-1.0.190-QA
111111/myProj-1.0.191-Dev
111111/myProj-1.0.192-Dev
111111/myProj-1.0.190-Prod
```

I would like to run a query that will get all log streams for group pattern `111111/myProj-1.0.*`. Is it possible using cli or sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the `describe-log-groups` [(docs here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-groups.html) along with the `filter-log-events` [(docs here)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/filter-log-events.html) aws cli commands to achieve this in bash:

```
for group in $(aws logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name-prefix "111111/myProj-1.0" | grep "logGroupName" | cut -d":" -f 2 | tr -d ",")
do
  aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name $group
done
```